# experiencing error while installing flair

Tags: visual-c++, pip, gensim, huggingface-transformers, flair

Im experiencing this error while running the command `pip install flair`

```
  building 'gensim.models.word2vec_inner' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gensim
```

I am running this command inside a conda environment. I was able to successfully install `flair` before. then i uninstalled miniconda, installed it on a separate drive (on the same pc) and tried installing `flair` again, thus here we are.

any help on how to resolve this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your `conda` version, & the Python version in the target environment? What if in a fresh environment, you try installing `gensim` using either `conda` or `pip` - do you get similar error?

Comment: @gojomo thanks, I installed `gensim` in my current environment and then ran `pip install flair` again. this time it installed without any errors.